# How to create synchronized view for output of all cells in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQn9aRc050w) shows how to create a synchronized view in a Jupyter notebook but it is tied to one cell's output. How can I do this but for any cell's outputs? Ideally something like the Plots viewer in RStudio.